# Split name and match part of the name to copy files

Tags: powershell

I am not programer and this is my the first encounter with Powershell.

I am trying to copy files based on exact part of the name of the file.
Here are examples of the files:

```
Z_080500032_1964_809_S.xlsx
Z_080600034_1963_805.csv
Z_080600034_1963_805_S_dolozka.xlsx
```

The part on based I am trying to copy files is the 3 digits number 805.
Z_080600034_1963_**805**_S_dolozka.xlsx
If I use only `-match` without spliting it copies all files which have 805 in their name. Which is not desirable because the 805 can appear on the front part of the name too

Here is code I created so far.

```
$path = "Z:\QNAP\EH\powershell"
$copypath = "Z:\QNAP\EH\powershell\copy\"
$filepath = Get-ChildItem $path\*.*
$kp = "\b805\b"

$String = $filepath.Name
$SplitArray = $String.Split("_.")

foreach ($item in $SplitArray) {
    if ($item -match $kp) {
    copy-item $filepath $copypath
    }
}
```

The $SplitArray gives correct data.

```
Z
080500032
1964
809
S
xlsx
Z
080600034
1963
805
csv
Z
080600034
1963
805
S
dolozka
xlsx
```

The match part
`$item -match $kp`
gives correct value

```
805
805
```

But when I try the full code, it copies all files. But it should copy only these two files.

```
Z_080600034_1963_805.csv
Z_080600034_1963_805_S_dolozka.xlsx
```

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: The match can be simply '_805[_.]'  The characters inside the square bracket allow more than one character.  You want the underscore followed by 805 and then either a underscore or a period.

Comment: Wouldn't this copy all the files every time?  `copy-item $filepath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All files are copied here

```php
copy-item $filepath $copypath
```

because the `$filepath` contains all `*.*` files from `$path` directory.

Instead, go through the files: split each name, check if any part matches `$kp` and if it does - copy this file.

```php
$path = "Z:\QNAP\EH\powershell"
$copypath = "Z:\QNAP\EH\powershell\copy\"
$filepathItems = Get-ChildItem $path\*.*
$kp = "\b805\b"

foreach ($fileItem in $filepathItems) {
    $splitArray = $fileItem.Name.Split("_")    
    foreach ($splitItem in $splitArray) {
        if ($splitItem -match $kp) {
            Copy-Item $fileItem $copypath
            break
        }
    }
}
```

A simplified version can also be used (as @jdweng suggested). It avoids `.Split("_")` and part matching:

```php
$path = "Z:\QNAP\EH\powershell"
$copypath = "Z:\QNAP\EH\powershell\copy\"
$filepathItems = Get-ChildItem $path\*.*
$kp = "_805[_.]"

$copyItems = $filepathItems | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $kp }
Copy-Item $copyItems $copypath
```

And a single line solution provided by @mklement0 in the comments:

```php
$path = "Z:\QNAP\EH\powershell"
$copyPath = "Z:\QNAP\EH\powershell\copy\"

Get-ChildItem -File $path\*.* | Where-Object Name -match "_805[_.]" | Copy-Item -Destination $copyPath
```

Comment: Nicely done; to do it all in one pipline: `Get-ChildItem -File $path\*.* | Where-Object Name -match $kp | Copy-Item -Destination $copyPath`

Comment: I like how \b matches a "." so you don't have to split with it.

Comment: Thank you all, I've updated the answer with suggested improvements.

Comment: These work perfectly. Thank you very much. I will use the one with splitarray and the single line solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost the same as the question.  You can use -match with an array and any result will be true.  Note that .split("_.") splits on each character in "_." individually. "\b" matches a period anyway (or a dash, but not an underscore).

```
echo hi | set-content Z_080500032_1964_809_S.xlsx, Z_080600034_1963_805.csv,
  Z_080600034_1963_805_S_dolozka.xlsx
mkdir foo

$path = "."
$copypath = "foo"
$filepath = get-childitem $path\*.* -exclude foo,script.ps1*
$kp = "\b805\b"

$String = $filepath.Name

foreach ($item in $String) {
    $SplitArray = $item.Split("_.")
    # if ($item -match '[_.]805[_.]') {
    if ($SplitArray -match $kp) {
      copy-item $item $copypath -whatif
    }
}


What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target
 "Item: C:\users\admin\foo\Z_080600034_1963_805.csv 
Destination: C:\users\admin\foo\foo\Z_080600034_1963_805.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target
 "Item: C:\users\admin\foo\Z_080600034_1963_805_S_dolozka.xlsx 
Destination: C:\users\admin\foo\foo\Z_080600034_1963_805_S_dolozka.xlsx".
```